# Jquery form - Change hidden value to option id

Tags: jquery, forms

Ah im racking my brain trying to figure this out. New to Jquery... as you will probably be able to tell soon...

Trying to use the option id to set the value of a hidden input, but hours in and hundreds of google searches with no solution.

I have figured out how to pull the value of the selected option using the selector ID but I want to get the ID of the option, so I can set that unique ID as the value of the hidden input.

```
<form>
<select name="amount" id="item_number1">
    <option value="1" id="11">one</option>
    <option value="2" id="22">two</option>
    <option value="3" id="33">three</option>
</select>
<input type="button" value="Set Value" onclick="$('#item_number2').val( $('#item_number1').val() )"/>
<input id="item_number2" type="text" />
```

Ps: the hidden input isnt in this form, In this form I am using a text input field so I can visualize if my method is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the id of the selected option like this:

```
<script>
$(function(){
  var sItem = document.getElementById("item_number1");
  $("#transfer").on("click", function(){
    $("#item_number2").val( sItem[sItem.selectedIndex].id );
  });
});
</script>
<input type="button" id="transfer" value="Transfer ID" />
<select name="amount" id="item_number1">
  <option value="1" id="11">one</option>
  <option value="2" id="22">two</option>
  <option value="3" id="33">three</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="item_number2" />
```

Note, you are not suppose to start your id values with a number - this may cause problems for you down the road. Best to adhere to the rules when it comes to stuff like this.

Demo: http://jsbin.com/ucujex/edit#javascript,html,live

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the ID, will have to adhere to that. But I am having a problem getting this to work. I replaced the other jquery function with this one and it doesn't seem to pull anything?

Comment: @mcflause I had provided a slightly different solution. Please check the code above. Remove the `onclick` attribute from your button.

Comment: Jonathan, this is perfect! You really went the extra mile and I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

You can update your button's `onclick` to:

```
$("#item_number2").val($("#item_number1 option:selected").attr("id"));
```

A nice improvement would be to have it automatically change when you change the option in the `select` (you wouldn't need the button).

```
$("#item_number1").change(function() {
    $("#item_number2").val($("option:selected", this).attr("id"));
});
```

Comment: Thanks dtbarne, I will deffinitely be implementing the change on select option to place the value into the hidden input.

Comment: Hey! I am trying to implement this with no luck, can you see what I am doing wrong? http://jsbin.com/anatod/edit#javascript,html,live

Comment: The javascript should be after the HTML. Also is a good idea to wrap jquery code in `$(document).ready()`

Comment: Ah I am so new, I just don't know all this stuff. Thank you very much I am absorbing all the info! Your the best thanks!

Comment: Glad to help. Thanks is best shown with upvotes and selecting best answers here though. :)

Comment: I know! I had to select the other one as best because it got the original answer. AND I need one more rep to be able to upvote, I will be coming right back to this post to upvote as soon as I get to 15 reps!!! Thanks!